# Numerical methods for 2nd order non-linear ODE $\ddot y=f(x)$ where $f$ is unknown

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Say we have a simple 2nd order non-linear ODE $\ddot y=f(x)$. We don't know what $f$ is but have several known data points $(x_1,f(x_1)),...,(x_n,f(x_n))$. Could you help suggest numerical methods (esp. **iterative algorithms**) to numerically estimate $y$? Any suggestion is helpful, including classic ones and new methods in recent researches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem can be reduced to an interpolation problem. I am pretty sure you are missing some initial conditions to solve the problem.

You can assume a polynomial as an interpolation function:
\begin{equation}
\hat{y}(x) = \sum^{n+1}_{k=0}a_k\,x^k
\end{equation}
If you differentiate the interpolation polynomial you get:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{\tfrac{d^2}{dx^2}}\hat{y}(x) = \sum^{n+1}_{k=2}k\,(k+1)\,a_{k-2}\,x^{k-2}
\end{equation}
The above polynomial providing the estimation of the second derivative can be found by a direct calculation of [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

You don't have to use Lagrange polynomial. As an alternative you can use splines. This gives you the estimation of the second derivative of a signal. To calculate the signal values you are still missing initial values.